# Returning two values pair in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have problem with this. Codeblocks error: 
cannot convert 'std::pair' to 'int' in return|
I can't return two values in my function. How can I do this?
I try also built structure but the same error...

Code:

```
int wyszukanieKR(char **tablica, char **wzorzec)
{
    pair <int, int> wspolrzedne;
    int hash_wzorzec = _hash(0, 0, 9, 3, wzorzec);
    int hash_tablica = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 84-9; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 13-3; j++)
        {
            hash_tablica = _hash(i, j, 9, 3, tablica);
            if(hash_wzorzec == hash_tablica)
            {
                bool znalazlem = false;
                for (int k = 0; k < 9; k++)
                {
                    for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++)
                    {
                        if (tablica[k+wspolrzedne.first][l+wspolrzedne.second] != wzorzec[k][l])
                            break;
                        if(k ==9 - 1 && l == 3 - 1)
                            znalazlem = true;
                    }
                }
                if(znalazlem)
                {
                    //cout<<"["<<wspolrzedne.first<<"]"<<"["<<wspolrzedne.second<<"]";
                    //return wspolrzedne;

                }
                licznik = licznik+1;
            }
            wspolrzedne.first++;
        }
        wspolrzedne.first = 0;
        wspolrzedne.second++;
    }
    //cout<<"["<<wspolrzedne.first<<"]"<<"["<<wspolrzedne.second<<"]";
    return wspolrzedne;
```

Comment: Why does the function have the return type int instead of std::pair?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem isn't that you can't return two items, it is that your return doesn't match your function declaration. You declare it as `int` but then try to return a `pair<int,int>`. These are not the same, so when the compiler tries to return one, it doesn't match the other, and gives you the error. What you need to do is either choose the value you want to return or change the declaration to

```
std::pair<int, int> wyszukanieKR(char **tablica, char **wzorzec)
```

Your total function should look like:

```
std::pair<int, int> wyszukanieKR(char **tablica, char **wzorzec)
{
    // Function Body
    return wspolrzedne; //pair<int, int>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this:

```
std::pair<int, int> wyszukanieKR(char **tablica, char **wzorzec)
{
  /* analysis */

  return std::make_pair<int,int>(pozycja_x,pozycja_y);
}
```

In the main you can use:

```
std::pair<int,int> result = wyszukanieKR(...);
std::cout << result.first << "  " <<result.second << "\n";
```

Comment: In main make_pair or pair?